# Extracting bigrams from corpus - error message

Tags: r, text

I have a SimpleCorpus and I want to create bigrams out of the text. When I use "SimpleCorpus", it only shows unigrams. When I switch my corpus to VCorpus, R does not find the `NGramTokenizer`  function anymore.. Can somebody help me with this problem or has any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)

someCleanText <- c("Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of",
                   "religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof or",
                   "abridging the freedom of speech or of the press or the",
                   "right of the people peaceably to assemble and to petition",
                   "the Government for a redress of grievances")

aCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(someCleanText))   #With this, only 1-Grams are created
#aCorpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(someCleanText)) #With this, biGrams are created as desired
    
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min=2, max=2))
    
aTDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(aCorpus, control=list(tokenize=BigramTokenizer))
      
print(aTDM$dimnames$Terms)
```

Comment: Don't know much about RWeka, but another simple and easy-to-use R library for creating bigrams, which I have used in production, is the UDPipe package (https://bnosac.github.io/udpipe/en/) . With its RAKE (Rapid Automatic Keywords Extraction) algorithm, you can easily extract bigrams from your corpus or corpora.